# Serializing objects for multiprocessing is slow -- is there a way to serialize just once?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I am trying to parallelize a function that takes in an object in Python:

In using Pathos, the map function automatically dills the object before distributing it among the processors.

However, it takes ~1 min to dill the object each time, and I need run this function up to 100 times. All in all, it is taking nearly 2 hours to just serialize the object before even running it.

Is there a way to just serialize it once, and use it multiple times?

Thanks very much

Comment: I'm just getting started with Python, but could this be a job for a Generator?

Comment: @asetniop it isn't obvious how that would help in the context.

Comment: Can you include a short example of how you are doing the parallelization? That way we don't have to guess about which MP functions you use.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to do this manually.

Without an example of your code, I have to make a lot of assumptions and write something pretty vague, so let's take the simplest case.

Assume you're using `dill` manually, so your existing code looks like this:

```
obj = function_that_creates_giant_object()
for i in range(zillions):
    results.append(pool.apply(func, (dill.dumps(obj),)))
```

All you have to do is move the `dumps` out of the loop:

```
obj = function_that_creates_giant_object()
objpickle = dill.dumps(obj)
for i in range(zillions):
    results.append(pool.apply(func, (objpickle,)))
```

But depending on your actual use, it may be better to just stick a cache in front of `dill`:

```
cachedpickle = functools.lru_cache(maxsize=10)(dill.dumps)

obj = function_that_creates_giant_object()
for i in range(zillions):
    results.append(pool.apply(wrapped_func, (cachedpickle(obj),))
```

---

Of course if you're monkeypatching `multiprocessing` to use `dill` in place of `pickle`, you can just as easy patch it to use this `cachedpickle` function.

---

If you're using `multiprocess`, which is a forked version of `multiprocessing` that pre-substitutes `dill` for `pickle`, it's less obvious how to patch that; you'll need to go through the source and see where it's using `dill` and get it to use your wrapper. But IIRC, it just does a `import dill as pickle` somewhere and then uses the same code as (a slightly out-of-date version of `multiprocessing`), so it isn't all that different.

In fact, you can even write a module that exposes the same interface as `pickle` and `dill`:

```
import functools
import dill

def loads(s):
    return dill.loads(s)

@lru_cache(maxsize=10)
def dumps(o):
    return dill.dumps(o)
```

… and just replace the `import dill as pickle` with `import mycachingmodule as pickle`.

… or even monkeypatch it after loading with `multiprocess.helpers.pickle = mycachingmodule` (or whatever the appropriate name is—you're still going to have to find where that relevant `import` happens in the source of whatever you're using).

---

And that's about as complicated as it's likely to get.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response!
I've tried the above implementation, but I am still running into the error: 
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed

It seems like the apply function is still trying to pickle the object after serialization. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @user154510 That doesn't make sense. The result of calling `pickle.dumps` (or a cached wrapper around it) is a `bytes`, and pickling a `bytes` can't raise that exception. My guess is that either you got some of the details wrong, or you didn't anticipate that, e.g., return values from pool tasks also get pickled. But I can't debug it without seeing some code.